# Scraping totally variable content between two tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

this is my first question on StackOverflow as I'm well and truly stumped. I'm using BeautifulSoup (and python, of course) to scrape a web database that in the past had been consistent and easy to scrape, but now has become difficult.

Previously the web content had been scraped from HTML:

```
<div class="title-class" valign="top">"Unique Title String"</div>
<div class="body-class" valign="top">"Unique Body String"</div>

<div class="title-class" valign="top">"Unique Title String 2"</div>
<div class="body-class" valign="top">"Unique Body String 2"</div>
```

The number of these divs is variable but it doesn't matter. I made lists of lists from the titles and bodies along with other relevant values then populated a spreadsheet. Easy.

Now, though, it seems some back-end person has gone off the deep end (this is government data, mind you) and the pages look like this:

```
<div class="title-class" valign="top">"Unique Title String"</div>
(HTML that is totally unique in every instance and contains random amount of tags and formatting.)
    
<div class="title-class" valign="top">"Unique Title String 2"</div>
(More HTML that is a totally unrelated brand of complete anarchy. If any element between these is the same twice it is pure coincidence.)
```

All of what I'm scraping is contained with a single  of a unique class. Within that  all these tags seem to have no children (from what I've examined). It's just a litany of tags with no hierarchy.

So clearly what I need to do is scrape all the content between each div of `title-class` and in the last `title-class` for each page, scrape the remainder of the content. Thing is I can't for the life of me figure out how to specify this in BeautifulSoup.

Any help as to how I might be able to do this is greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: if you have example webpage would be helpful

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: @AMC Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the rest of the page look like? Is there no simpler way to parse/access the correct elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. You want to find sections between various titles and last section as well. This example will group the sections to dictionary, where the key is title of section:

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<b>I don't want this</b>

<div class="title-class" valign="top">"Unique Title String 1"</div>
<a>111</a><b>some</b><i>tags</i><b>I want</b><i>to scrap</i>
    
<div class="title-class" valign="top">"Unique Title String 2"</div>
<a>222</a><b>some</b><i>tags</i><b>I want</b><i>to scrap</i>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

titles = soup.find_all('div', class_='title-class')

out = {}
for tag in soup.find_all(recursive=False):
    prev_title = tag.find_previous('div', class_='title-class')
    if prev_title and tag not in titles:
        out.setdefault(prev_title, []).append(tag)

pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{<div class="title-class" valign="top">"Unique Title String 2"</div>: [<a>222</a>,
                                                                       <b>some</b>,
                                                                       <i>tags</i>,
                                                                       <b>I want</b>,
                                                                       <i>to scrap</i>],
 <div class="title-class" valign="top">"Unique Title String 1"</div>: [<a>111</a>,
                                                                       <b>some</b>,
                                                                       <i>tags</i>,
                                                                       <b>I want</b>,
                                                                       <i>to scrap</i>]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, then here's one approach using [next_sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
<div class="title-class" valign="top">Some title</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</div>
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
<div class="title-class" valign="top">Some other title</div>
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</p>
<div class="title-class" valign="top">Yet another title</div>
<p>cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
'''

f = StringIO(data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')

sections = []
for d in soup.select('div.title-class'):
    sections.append((d.text, []))
    n = d.next_sibling
    while n:
        if n.name=='div' and 'title-class' in n.get('class', []):
            break

        sections[-1][-1].append(str(n))
        n = n.next_sibling

from pprint import pprint
pprint(sections)
```

Comment: This seems to be a perfect solution. But I have a newb question: my script is basically a large loop as I have to iterate through thousands of web pages using POST parameters, so  as I reach the the end of `while n:` I'd want to `continue` not `break`, right?

Comment: `break` is used to stop (break out of) a loop when a condition is satisfied; `continue` skips the current item if a condition is satisfied or something breaks. I assume you don't want to skip the matched item, but rather focus on it, so `break` is what you want!